# add a youtube video link in mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a video sharing platform where anyone can add youtube videos and their preferred image But for the backend I am using mongodb for that I am creating  mongoose schema I need to add youtube video link to the schema which also validates whether it is a youtube video link or not so how can I achieve his task

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validate = require("validator");
const config = require("../config/config");



const videoSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title :{
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        genre:{
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        viewCount :{
            type: Number,
            default: config.default_view_count,
        },
        releaseDate :{
            type : Date,
            required: true,
            default: Date.now,
        },
        votes :{
            type: [Object],
            upvotes: {
                type: Number,
            },
            downvotes:{
                type: Number,
            }
        },
        contentrating: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
          },
        previewimage:{
            type: 'image/png',
            required: true,
        }
      
    },
    //create createdAt and updateAt field automatically
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
)

const Video =  mongoose.model('Video',videoSchema)
module.exports = {Video};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your link is just a simple youtube link and you're looking to check it's validity, you can use the youtube API and request information about the video pointed to by that link.

There's an example that requests information about a specific video :

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#Sample_Partial_Requests

If no information or an error is returned, then you know it's an invalid link.

Comment: I'm glad ! If this solves your problem, do mark this an a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess an easy way is to just validate if the video link starts with `https://www.youtube.com/`. You can add a new field to your Schema Model and add validation to that field. If validation fails, document will not be stored and an error will be thrown.

You can add a new `youtube_video_link` field in your Schema Model like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validate = require("validator");
const config = require("../config/config");



const videoSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title :{
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        genre:{
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        viewCount :{
            type: Number,
            default: config.default_view_count,
        },
        releaseDate :{
            type : Date,
            required: true,
            default: Date.now,
        },
        votes :{
            type: [Object],
            upvotes: {
                type: Number,
            },
            downvotes:{
                type: Number,
            }
        },
        contentrating: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        previewimage:{
            type: 'image/png',
            required: true,
        },
        youtube_video_link: {
            type: String,
            validate: {
               validator: function(v) {
                    return /^https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/.*$/.test(v);
               },
               message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid youtube link.`
            },
            required: [true, 'Youtube video link is required.']
        }
    },
    //create createdAt and updateAt field automatically
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
)

const Video =  mongoose.model('Video',videoSchema)
module.exports = {Video};
```